# How do I make a h1 and h3 only as wide as the text

Tags: html, css

```css
.main-heading {
  display: block;
  font-family: "Josefin-Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 70.6px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ba9a45;
}

.subheading {
  font-family: "Cardo", sans-serif;
  font-size: 23.5px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Headings -->

<div>
  <h1 class="main-heading">ATLANTIC</h1>
  <h1 class="main-heading">CASINO</h1>
  <h3 class="subheading">FEED YOUR DESIRES</h3>
</div>
```

I seem to not be able to make my **h1** and **h3** background only as wide as the text and not span the **whole width** of the line.

How can I reduce the background of the **h1** and **h3** so it only spans to the end of the text?

--

I've managed to resolve my issue by taking into consideration all the advice given by users below.

Have a look at my revised code which works:

```
<div class="title-headings">
  <h1 class="main-heading">ATLANTIC</h1>
  <h1 class="main-heading">CASINO</h1>
  <h3 class="subheading">FEED YOUR DESIRES</h3>
</div>


.main-heading{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: max-content;
  font-family: "Josefin-Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 70.6px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ba9a45;
}

.subheading{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: max-content;
  font-family: "Cardo", sans-serif;
  font-size: 23.5px;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

Comment: `display: inline-block`

Comment: `h1{width:max-content;}` vould do. Or `h1{display:table;}`. 2 ways to keep it à block element.

Comment: Do you want to change the width or the font size?

Answer (score 2):

Headings (`<h1>`, `<h2>`, ...) are block-level elements (`display: block`); if you want these to only take up as much space as the text is, you should set these to `display: inline`.

Comment: ... side by side in the end. Is this what the op asked for?

Comment: Have a look at my revised code with the solution I desired above in my question description.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do it by:

```
.element{
    display: inline-block
}
```

It will now take up only the width it is supposed to take!

Answer (score 1):

Whilst the comments and other answers are correct in that - display : inline-block is the correct answer if the text was to be on one line, they do not address the fundamental semantic flaw in the code - you should have only one h1 element and for that to be followed by a h2.

It is important to maintain the correct hierarchy or headings in your page structure.

The way that I would do this is to have the h1 to be display: inline-block and within that to have spans for each word - and to have these spanss a display: block  so that they are on separate lines.

Note that I added a red border to demonstrate the layout. And also added a text-align: center to the wrapping div to allow al lthe text to be centered.

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
}

.main-heading {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Josefin-Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 70.6px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ba9a45;
  border: solid 1px red
}

.main-heading span {
  display: block;
 }

.subheading {
  font-family: "Cardo", sans-serif;
  font-size: 23.5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- Headings -->

<div>
  <h1 class="main-heading">
    <span>ATLANTIC</span>
    <span>CASINO</span>
  </h1>
  <h2 class="subheading">FEED YOUR DESIRES</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: I have taken on board everything you said just by fiddling around with my code and this is my result. I just want my code to be as clean as possible. 

.main-heading{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: max-content;
  font-family: "Josefin-Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 70.6px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ba9a45;
}

.subheading{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: max-content;
  font-family: "Cardo", sans-serif;
  font-size: 23.5px;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

Comment: What I've basically done is use my classes .main-heading and .subheading to make my content have a max-width of content - not needing to target h1 or h3 specifically in my css. And I have also retained the centre alignment of my content by using margin auto.

Answer (score 0):

To make a block HTML element not span the full width of its container, change its `style.display` property to `inline-block`.

You can do it with CSS like this:

```
display: inline-block
```

If you wanted to do it in the element itself, the equivalent would be:
`style="display: inline-block;"`

Answer (score 0):

On `.main-heading` change `display:block;` to `display:inline-block;`

```css
.main-heading {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Josefin-Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 70.6px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ba9a45;
}

.subheading {
  font-family: "Cardo", sans-serif;
  font-size: 23.5px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 class="main-heading">ATLANTIC</h1>
  <h1 class="main-heading">CASINO</h1>
  <h3 class="subheading">FEED YOUR DESIRES</h3>
</div>
```